# Elasticsearch 6.0: how to install license plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have a pretty fresh install of Elasticsearch running, with X-pack installed. I'm trying to install sheild from [Getting Started with Sheild](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/shield/current/getting-started.html). If I run `bin/plugin install license` from `/usr/local/elasticsearch` (OS X), I get `No such file or directory`. Indeed, there is no `bin/plugin` directory.

If I follow [Installing Plugins](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/installation.html), from `sudo bin/elasticsearch-plugin install [plugin_name]`, I get a list of commands and options, but it doesn't look like anything installs.

The Getting Started with Shield section does mention `ES_HOME`, but doesn't explain what this is.

How do I install the license plugin into Elasticsearch?

Comment: AFAIK, Shield is now part of X-pack, you don't need to install it. But only its license through [license endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-license.html).

Comment: Ah, ok. I missed the note at the top of the page. "From version 5.0 onward, Shield is part of X-Pack. For more information, see Securing Elasticsearch and Kibana in the X-Pack Reference."

Comment: If you post your point as an answer, I will mark it as the correct solution, which it is since this Elasticsearch 6.0 is being used.

Comment: Done. Glad to help you @BBaysinger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Shield is now part of X-pack, you don't need to install it. But only its license through [license endpoint](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/x-pack/current/installing-license.html):

```
curl -XPUT -u elastic 'http://<host>:<port>/_xpack/license' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @license.json
```